# How to draw and label a vertical line from datapoint to x-axis in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following figure that consists of only four different values of `$x$`. Each of these `$x$` values corresponds to a certain dataset and I need to label it in the figure.

Therefore, I want to draw a vertical line from top to bottom of this plot and have a label (a string not a number) for that in `x`-axis. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    xlabel=$x$,
                    ylabel=Running Time (sec),
                    xmode=log,
                    every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
                    ]
                \addplot[color=green,mark=triangle*,mark size=2] coordinates {
                    (735323,3.477)
                    (875713,8.598)
                    (986324,6.697)
                    (4847571,54.948)
                };
                \addplot[color=blue,mark=square*,mark size=2,mark options={solid}] coordinates {
                    (735323,2.759941)
                    (875713,3.898159)
                    (986324,3.172807)
                    (4847571,72.299393)
                };
                \addplot[color=purple,mark=*,mark size=2,mark options={solid}] coordinates {
                    (735323,1.607309)
                    (875713,4.377542)
                    (986324,4.460953)
                    (4847571,34.504368)
                };
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may better use a bar plot for such a purpose. You have 4 points for the same (each) x value. From which point you want to draw a line?

Comment: @HarishKumar I want to show the trend, that's why I used the line chart. For each x coordinate used (only four used coordinates: 735323, 875713, 875713, 4847571) and Each can have a label such as L1, L2, L3 and L4.

Comment: What should be the top point of the line? bottom point is on x axis, I got it. But.. [Is it like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7LMkv.png)

Comment: @HarishKumar That's good, it's better to have it stick to the top. But either way is clear.

Comment: You mean top line of the box?

Comment: @HarishKumar yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    ymin=-10,clip=false,
                    xlabel=$x$,
                    ylabel=Running Time (sec),
                    xmode=log,
                    every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
                    extra x ticks={735323,875713,986324,4847571},
                    extra x tick labels={$L_1$,$L_2$,$L_3$,$L_4$},
                    extra x tick style={x tick label style={yshift=-2ex,rotate=90,anchor=east},grid=major,major grid style={draw=blue, thick}}
                    ]
                \addplot[color=green,mark=triangle*,mark size=2] coordinates {
                    (735323,3.477)
                    (875713,8.598)
                    (986324,6.697)
                    (4847571,54.948)
                };
                \addplot[color=blue,mark=square*,mark size=2,mark options={solid}] coordinates {
                    (735323,2.759941)
                    (875713,3.898159)
                    (986324,3.172807)
                    (4847571,72.299393)
                };
                \addplot[color=purple,mark=*,mark size=2,mark options={solid}] coordinates {
                    (735323,1.607309)
                    (875713,4.377542)
                    (986324,4.460953)
                    (4847571,34.504368)
                };
                %\draw[blue] (axis cs: 4847571,72.299393) -- (axis cs: 4847571,-10)node[anchor=east,rotate=90]{Some label};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also draw them by yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    ymin=-10,clip=false,
                    xlabel=$x$,
                    ylabel=Running Time (sec),
                    xmode=log,
                    every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},                    
                    ]
                \addplot[color=green,mark=triangle*,mark size=2] coordinates {
                    (735323,3.477)
                    (875713,8.598)
                    (986324,6.697)
                    (4847571,54.948)
                };
                \addplot[color=blue,mark=square*,mark size=2,mark options={solid}] coordinates {
                    (735323,2.759941)
                    (875713,3.898159)
                    (986324,3.172807)
                    (4847571,72.299393)
                };
                \addplot[color=purple,mark=*,mark size=2,mark options={solid}] coordinates {
                    (735323,1.607309)
                    (875713,4.377542)
                    (986324,4.460953)
                    (4847571,34.504368)
                };
                \draw[blue] (axis cs: 4847571,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
                      (axis cs: 4847571,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})node[anchor=west,rotate=90]{Some label};
                \draw[blue] (axis cs: 986324,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
                      (axis cs: 986324,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})node[anchor=west,rotate=90]{Some};
                \draw[blue] (axis cs: 875713,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
                      (axis cs: 875713,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})node[anchor=west,rotate=90]{Some label};
                \draw[blue] (axis cs: 735323,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
                      (axis cs: 735323,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})node[anchor=west,rotate=90]{Some};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]